# Can I disable autocomplete with Alt+Tab on Qt Creator under Linux?

Tags: linux, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator, alt-tab

For the most part I very much like Qt Creator, but a few projects I'm working on require me to switch between my editor and my web browser for reference. Qt Creator is currently interpreting Alt+Tab to autocomplete, and then switching my window focus; this is a mild problem but it's really starting to get to me.

I've tried going to Tools→Options→Keyboard and searching for Alt+Tab, but found nothing. Is there a way to get it to selectively ignore the key combination without disabling autocomplete on the whole?

To complete the picture, I'm on Linux Mint 19.04 using XFCE desktop environment; or occasionally Maté. If I need to access something in system settings to do this I'm happy to; I just don't want to keep excessively second-guessing my code when I return to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-complete is bound to Ctrl+Space by default, not Alt+Tab. In tools/options/keyboard, search for "CompleteThis" to see what it's bound to.

Maybe what you want is to disable auto-complete and use only manual-complete? That is, have the auto-complete list only show when you press ctrl+space, but never automatically. You can do that in options/text editor/completion.

Comment: CompleteThis is indeed bound to control+space. Perhaps I should clarify? The autocomplete drop-down menu makes a selection on alt+tab, I would like it to ignore this key combination. I'm not completely sure that it's possible now.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin That's because of tab, not alt+tab. Maybe what you want is to disable auto-complete and use only manual-complete? That is, have the auto-complete list only show when you press ctrl+space, but never automatically. You can do that in options/text editor/completion.